# How to set UTF-16 encoding format for Xml?

Tags: java, xml, xml-serialization, xsd

I am in need to create xml as a string to pass to server. I have managed to convert the data into xml but the encoding format set to utf-8 as default. What i need is i want to set it as utf-16 format. But i haven't got any idea of setting it.

```
  private void XmlCreation(int size,List<DataItem> item) throws ParserConfigurationException, TransformerException
 {
  DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
  DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
  Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();
  Element rootElement = document.createElement("ArrayOfDataItem");
  document.appendChild(rootElement);
  for (DataItem in: item)
  { 
  Element subroot = document.createElement("DataItem"); 
  rootElement.appendChild(subroot);
  Element em = document.createElement(in.getKey());
  em.appendChild(document.createTextNode(in.getValue()));
  subroot.appendChild(em); 
  }

  TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
  Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
  java.io.StringWriter sw = new java.io.StringWriter();
  DOMSource source = new DOMSource(document);

  StreamResult result =  new StreamResult(System.out);
  transformer.transform(source, result);

  String xml = sw.toString();
  System.out.println(xml);
  }
}
```

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This](http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/excerpt/java_xslt_ch5/index.html?page=4) article might help you. Basically, you call `setOutputProperty` with `OutputKeys.ENCODING` as key and the desired encoding ("UTF-16") as value.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't tested, but that should do the trick:

```
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-16");
```