# How to set an xml declaration in XOM use Java?

Tags: java, xml, xom

```
Element element = new Element("root");
Document document = new Document(element);
```

document will auto generate `<?xml version="1.0"?>`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
</root>
```

How to set encoding, standalone into xml declaration use XOM ?
I expect:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16" standalone="yes"?>
<root>
</root>
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10582968/how-to-set-utf-16-encoding-format-for-xml

Comment: If not a duplicate then see http://www.xom.nu/tutorial.xhtml, `Serializer serializer = new Serializer(System.out, "ISO-8859-1");`

Comment: @klog Thanks for reply, but Serializer(OutputStream out, String encoding) , how to set "standalone"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: you can't do that.

XOM deliberately does not expose or emit the standalone declaration. In 18 years of XML, I can't recall a single case where the standalone declaration has been necessary or useful; and XOM makes a point of shielding developers from features they shouldn't concern themselves with.

The standalone declaration likely doesn't do what you think it does in any case. For instance, both of the highest voted answers on [What does the 'standalone' directive mean in XML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578645/what-does-the-standalone-directive-mean-in-xml) are *wrong*. I'll add a correct answer to that question when I get a minute.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.